# Unable to install Mac OS X 10.4 onto USB flash drive

Tags: usb, install, flash-memory

I am trying to install Mac OS X 10.4 onto a USB flash drive with the DVD. (not creating a bootable USB installer!) When I reach the "Select Destination" part of the installation, I  select the USB flash drive, but then I see a small red octagon with an exclamation mark next to the volume's icon. Below it is the same red octagon with the message:

`You cannot install Mac OS X on this volume. Mac OS X cannot start up from this volume.`

and the **Options** and **Continue** buttons are greyed out. What does this mean? Does it mean that Mac OS X cannot be installed on USB flash drives? Or is the install destination corrupted?

Comment: How have you formatted the USB Flash Drive?

Comment: @IconDaemon I erased the drive because it originally had Parallels Desktop on it so I can use it as a backup disk. I formatted it as Mac OS Extended.

Comment: What model of Mac? Is the install DVD the one that came with the Mac, came with another Mac (which model?), or a later purchase?

Comment: Format of USB may need to be APT/HFS+. From web searches, success more likely with powered drive.

Comment: I'm not sure what the end goal is here, but Macs couldn't boot from USB back in 10.4 days [2005]. First USB-bootable Macs were '08 or '09.